# domain poiting to website

Tags: dns, mapping, subdomain

I have a a website on my server on a subdomain. let's say at this adress:
subdomain.sourceserver.com/site/

I mapped a freshly bought domain (mynewdomain.com) to my server. So now  mynewdomain.com resolves with the IP of my server. 
And http://mynewdomain.com displays the website located at subdomain.source-server.com/site/

When I start browsing in the pages of the website, the adress displayed changes back to http://subdomain.sourceserver.com/site/blabla.php

I would like to keep it with the domain name:
http://mynewdomain.com/blabla.php

How can I do that ?

Do I have to create a CName on the DNS zone subdomain.sourceserver.com ?

Thanks in advance !
Cheers,
Mat

Answer (score 1):

DNS is not what's changing the address in your browser, it is likely your web code or web server config. My suspicion is that your site is configured to be "subdomain.sourceserver.com/site/", so links inside the site are pointed at "http://subdomain.sourceserver.com/site/something.file", which is why the visible URL changes.

http://mynewdomain.com is resolving to the same IP address as your previous name, so your web browser is taking you to the same content. Unless you have virtual hosts configured so that the server pays attention to the headers, it will simply serve out the content to the request that lands on it's IP:port.

[Virtual host examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Thank mate. When I check the generated html code of the website, I can see that the links are pointing to subdomain.sourceserver.com/site/etc... I'll try to set up virtual host on the server. Thanks !